# Non object error when using prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have a table containing columns person and person_initials. When Submit is clicked I would like to insert the name in the input box into the person column in the table of names where the initial equals the initial defined. In this case only 1 row containing "I" in the person_initial column exists in the table.
Please see the code below. I'm sure there must be a basic syntax error in the prepared statement but I can't see it. Apologies for the ignorance.

index.php:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
Insert: <input type="text" name="q" value="Tim"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['q'])) {
$test_name = $_POST['q'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "personnames";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

      if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      }

$people = 'I';
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO names (person) VALUE=(?) where  
person_initial=(?)");

$stmt->bind_param("ss",$test_name,$people);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();   
} 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: INSERT doesn't have a `where` clause. INSERT ON DUPLICATE does as does INSERT SELECT http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html. Edit: and UPDATE as stated by Steve. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html --- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to do an SQL UPDATE not an INSERT

Comment: *"When Submit is clicked I would like to **insert** the name in the input box into the person column"* - Funny, that isn't what you said in the answer you accepted *"Yes of course an update rather than an insert - I feel so silly"* - Steve was right all along, both in his comment above, and in his answer below. Where does ***update*** come into gear here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `INSERT` query is wrong. Use

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO names (person) VALUES(?)");
```

instead

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO names (person) VALUE=(?) where  
person_initial=(?)");
```

If you want to update, then use update query like this

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE names SET person=? where person_initial=?");
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Yes of course an update rather than an insert - I feel so silly

Answer (score 2):

You seem to attempting an update, in which case the syntax would be:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE names SET person=? where person_initial=?");
```

Comment: Pretty sure they want to do an INSERT there Steve. *"When Submit is clicked I would like to insert the name in the input box into the person column"*

Comment: @Fred-ii- maybe, its hard to tell.`"In this case only 1 row containing "I" in the person_initial column exists in the table"` Led me to believe to opposite, but only the OP knows

Comment: Well, the OP states  now in the accepted answer: *"Yes of course an update rather than an insert - I feel so silly"* - so I upvoted. You were right all along.

Comment: Plus, your answer's timestamp is the first one submitted. [Jim Morrison said it best](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People_Are_Strange), didn't he?